# MySQL Transactions in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, transactions

I am trying to implement some sort of transaction and keep failing.

Here is my code:

```
PreparedStatement ac = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Stock "
        + "SET Stock= Stock - ('"+stockinput+"')"
        + "WHERE StockID =('"+stockID+"')");
ac.executeUpdate();
PreparedStatement dc = con.prepareStatement("SELECT StockAmount FROM Stock");
ResultSet results = dc.executeQuery();
while(results.next()){
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(results.getString("StockAmount"));
    if(stockinput < temp ){
        con.rollback();
    }
    else{
        con.commit();
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't rollback.

Have spent nearly an hour trying to find a fix.

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the first line.

I'd suggest that you need to learn more about JDBC.  Who would be so foolish as to use PreparedStatement and not use bind variables?

I wouldn't like this logic, anyway.  If the stock amount shouldn't be negative, I'd add that as a constraint in the database. And why check after you've done the UPDATE?  Check before.  This code makes little sense.

```
// i don't see this in your code.
con.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ac = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Stock "
        + "SET Stock= Stock - ('"+stockinput+"')"
        + "WHERE StockID =('"+stockID+"')");
ac.executeUpdate();
PreparedStatement dc = con.prepareStatement("SELECT StockAmount FROM Stock");
ResultSet results = dc.executeQuery();
while(results.next()){
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(results.getString("StockAmount"));
    if(stockinput < temp ){
        con.rollback();
    }
    else{
        con.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work :(, I put this code right at the start of the try{ } block

Answer (score 0):

set the connection to autocommit(false);

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

How to use prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement ac = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Stock "
        + "SET Stock= Stock - (?) "
        + "WHERE StockID = ?;
ac.setInt(1, stockinput); // setString or whatever data type
ac.setString(2, stockID);
```

PreparedStatements precompiles and stores in a SQL statement. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.